# Can jQuery replace a linked image when link is active?

Tags: jquery

I am currently trying to achieve something pretty simple, at least in my eyes, however for some reason it's impossible to achieve. But I am guessing it can be done with jQuery though. But I lack the skills.

I have a few menu items for example:

- Home
- News
- Fun
- Contact

All of those links open a new page.

Now I am using images for those links. And I want an image over the current image, when a link is active (not hover).

With CSS this can be done pretty easily when all links are located on the same page with anchor points (a.home-link:active). However this of course does not work when linked to a different page.

Can this be done with jQuery...?

**Update:**

Someone adviced me to use: `$("#myImage").attr("src", "path/to/newImage.jpg");`

So I did it like this:

Step 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Step 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#testlink").attr("src", "active.png");
</script>
```

Step 3:

```
<a class="active" href="testpage.php"><img src="standard.png" alt="standard" width="64" height="64" border="0" /></a>
```

But that didn't work, because it doesn't do anything at all.... :(

**//Update #2**

Well I appreciate the answers and the effort from you guys, but I cannot get this working. I don't think this should be so difficult to achieve.

Maybe I didn't explain everything correctly, so I will try to explain it better this time by giving a better example.

With CSS and anchor points, you can format the link which is active, in this case display a different image. When nothing has been clicked the non-active.png will be shown, if one of the links is clicked (and active) it would show active.png for the active link (I don't want any hover effects, only active and not-active).

This can be done easily with anchor points normally when everything is on the same page, however since my links point to different pages, this obviously doesn't work. If I use anchor points in this situation, the clicked link won't be active anymore and will remain not-active.

Maybe this is a better explanation of what I am trying to achieve. Maybe I don't even need jQuery, but I thought this has to be used to get the desired effect I am looking for...?

Thanks once again and again I am sorry for asking stupid questions.

Comment: You should use `$(document).ready(function() { });` in your "Step 2" and I can´t see any element with ID "testlink".

Comment: By "active" do you really refer to the dynamic pseudo-class `:active` or do you want something more like storing the current selected tab?

Comment: Uhmz... What is the difference? I only want my links, which are images, to change when that link is active. For example I click on the news link (and it opens the news page) the news link would be active and show the active link image.

If someone clicks than on the Home link (the index.php) will be opened and the link called Home would be active and display the active home image.

Comment: Ok, that´s what I thought. You should not be looking at the pseudo-class `:active` then. How does your links look like? `href="testpage.php"` is the one I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply back. Sorry for the late response, but I had an headache yesterday (probably because of this mess of mine). But yes, I use links like href="index.php", href="fotos.php", etc. Thanks for helping out! Highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you pages (index.php and foto.php) sharing the HTML for the menu? Are you using any include or have you copy/pasted the HTML?

Comment: No they are not sharing the HTML for the menu. I am looking into it, if it would be possible. That would solve a lot of problems as well...

Comment: That way it will be much easier to maintain but it won´t markup the selected menu link to highlight. If you could set a different CSS class on the `body` tag serverside (using PHP) for each page you´re almost there!

Comment: Can you give me an example, because I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, you give the body-tag an id or class, but how do you make it interact with an active link?

Comment: I posted a complete answer for you, hope it´s enough! :)

Comment: Nevermind. Replied to your detailed answer instead! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you´re able to set the ID/class attribute on your body tag for each page you could use that to target the menu link for the current (active) page.

```
<body id="page-<?= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php")?>">
```

See [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) for more information about the example.

When each page `body` as well as each menu link has it´s own unique ID/class you´re able to use CSS to style the menu link for the current page.

I put together this small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2G8xT/) for you;

**HTML**

```
<body id="page-home">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="nav-home"><a href="#home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li id="nav-foto"><a href="#foto.php">Foto</a></li>
    </ul>    
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#page-home #nav-home a,
#page-foto #nav-foto a
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #cea;
}
```

As you will see the menu links will change appearance depending on the ID/class of the `body` tag.

You can read more about this at [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/id-your-body-for-greater-css-control-and-specificity/) that has a great article about this.

Comment: Thanks man! I was doing something like that as well, but your code is much better actually. Thanks man. I will make this to good use!

Highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what your jQuery script is doing:

```
$("#testlink") // fetch the element with id "testlink"
.attr("src", "active.png"); // sets its source to "active.png"
```

Now, it's plain why this doesn't work: You don't have an element with ID "testlink".

Set the image you want to change the source of to have that ID, and it should work just dandy.

If i understand you correctly, you want the link to the page the user is on to be marked up in some manner - the best way to go about this is however probably not to use JavaScript, but instead a server-side language. That way, you can just add a class (say, "active") to the link that should be decorated, and do the magic with CSS.

Comment: Oops I made an error with that, but it still doesn't work. :S



`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#testlink").attr("src", "active.png");
</script> `


`<a id="testlink" href="testpage.php"><img src="standard.png" alt="standard" width="64" height="64" border="0" /></a>`


Still doesn't work. :S



Nor does: `<a href="testpage.php"><img src="standard.png" alt="standard" width="64" height="64" border="0" id="testlink" /></a>`

Ugh, I cannot get my reply even properly formatted. sorry. :(

Comment: Well active would work if everything was on the same page (hence anchor points), however this does not work if the link point to a different page. I thought I mentioned this in my question, if not I am sorry.

Comment: Well, you're still using trying to set the "src" property on a link. If anything, you should get the img-tag contained within the link with id "testlink", like this: `$("#testlink img").attr("src", "path/to/file.png")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#testlink").attr("src", "active.png");
 </script>

 <a class="active" href="testpage.php"><img id="testlink" src="standard.png" alt="standard" width="64" height="64" border="0" /></a>
```

Notice the addition of an id to the img tag.

Or:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#testlink img").attr("src", "active.png");
 </script>

 <a id="testlink" class="active" href="testpage.php"><img src="standard.png" alt="standard" width="64" height="64" border="0" /></a>
```

Combine the code above with: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Thanks I tried both codes, but nothing changes. It stays on the same image. It's official; I am stupid. :(

Comment: Combine the code that I gave you with the info here:  http://api.jquery.com/hover/